# autologging into a website

Tags: java, httpclient, web-scraping, autologin

I want to login into a website. I need to identify the url to login. The view source shows post method as follows.

```
<form id="signIn" onsubmit="return false;" action="/f1/logon" method="post">
```

I see that there is no javascript that validates the url.
When i use the below url directly on a browser,

```
https://www.abc.com/f1/logon
```

I get a blank page. When I use below,

```
https://www.abc.com/logon
```

I dont see the repsonse of the loggedin page. It shows the response of the signin page though. How do i identify the correct url to autologin. downloaded soem toold like fiddler but no help. any inputs?

Comment: did you use 'fi' <eff-eye> or 'f1' <eff-one>?

Comment: @ Kelly...what is eff-eye?eff-one?

Comment: I was distinguishing between the number '1' and the lowercase i'.  The URLs you posted don't match:  from view-source you show  `action="/f1/logon"` vs your direct URL of `https://www.abc.com/f1/logon`. I noticed that the view-source version used the numeral '1' and your direct URL used the letter 'i'.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a URL in a browser sends a GET request.  This form, however, is configured to send a POST request (look at the `method` attribute), so it makes sense that you are not seeing anything in your browser.

It's strange that the `onsubmit` attribute returns false.  This prevents the form from being submitted at all.  Take a look at the "login" button.  There may be some Javascript code there which does the form submission.

Comment: @javaiText Yes there is.  `return false;`

Comment: @Michael...this is the code for sign In "<li><div class="btn xlRed" id="login_std" tabindex="1"><div><p>Sign In</p></div></div></li>"

Comment: @javaiText Michael means the form tag. Look at the onsubmit attribute.

Comment: Oh sorry i mis read. Now i checked for onsubmit event and I dont see anything in the view source page for this event.

Answer (score 0):

Fidller is a good tool, you can start capture job and then you perform a login. Find which request contain your login and password.